# Adobe Premiere Pro exports still images with white dots over entire screen

Tags: export, adobe-premiere

Adobe Premiere Pro 2022

I exported a video using the following parameters:

```
Preset - Custom
Format - H.264
Frame size - Custom - 640 x 360
Frame rate - 29.97
Field order - Progressive
Aspect - Square Pixels(1.0)
Bitrate Encoding - VBR, 1 pass
Target Bitrate - 4
Max Bitrate - 4
```

Generally I'm satisfied with the resulting quality except that part where a still image is rendered having some white dots running from top to bottom over the entire screen.

The blue area should be clean blue without any dots.

For some reason on the image below the dots are not white but green.

How to avoid them?

[image]